# Mangle and mark packets in the same iptables chain

Tags: iptables

I want to mangle packets by redirecting them to the NFQUEUE target, but at the same time, I want to mark them in the same chain which is the PREROUTING Chain.

To redirect packets to the NFQUEUE target I use:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

To mark packets value I use (here icmp is just an example):

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p icmp -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

Is there any way to do both manipulations at the same time?

any help would be very appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem I used the raw table (which is used in principal to mark packets) to redirect packets and the mangle table to mark them:

```
 iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```